# Changing one word's color in Linux terminal/Putty?

Tags: linux, terminal, makefile, putty

Do you think there is a way of changing a specific word's color on the Linux terminal or on Putty?

I'm using the "make" command though terminal (and putty sometimes), and I just thought of how nice it would be if among all the warnings, the printed line containing the **"error:"** would be in red/marked somehow.

It doesn't really matter, because I guess the solution would be somehow terminal recognizing a specific word related, but just for clarafication - I'm compiling a makefile of C/Assembly code.

There is off course the solution of not printing the warnings at all, but I want to see the warnings.

Thanks,
Barak.

Comment: You want to color only "error:" or the whole line containing the error?

Comment: Both will work @Dogbert... I just want it to pop out... (better just the word I guess).

Answer (score 0):

See the [ANSI terminal escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).  Most terminals implement them.

For example, to display a word in red:

```
The word at the end is in <Esc>[31m red <Esc>[30m .
```

I have inserted some spaces for clarity, which should be removed.

Unfortunately, this assumes that the foreground color is initially black.  If the text is originally white on a black background, this will make subsequent text seem to disappear.  (I say *seem* because it is there and can be viewed by selecting the text.)